# How to only allow landscape orientation on an iPad?

Tags: ios4, ipad

So I've already tried setting the Supported Interface Orientations key in my iPad app's Info.plist to support both landscape modes. However when I put my iPad in a portrait orientation, my screen rotates. Because of the way my app is designed I only want my app to display itself in either landscape modes, how can I do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Setting the `Info.plist` key is mainly used for determining the orientation of your app at startup. If your view controllers return `YES` for a given orientation from [shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW23), the interface will be allowed to orient itself that way, regardless of what the `Info.plist` says. The solution is to only allow landscape orientations in that method:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation);
}
```

Comment: I did this but my app still allows one of the Portrait mode. How come? This happens on iOS 5.1, but on iOS 6.0 it's perfect.

Comment: Just to clarify, this chunk of code goes in each view controller.

Answer (score 0):

return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);